# Unexpected number when passing value in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax-error, typeerror

I am getting the below error when am passing value to `$scope.formData.field_happy.und.0.value`.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

But if am passing it binding to a model it seems to work. I can't figure out what am doing wrong.

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="formData.field_staff_interaction.und.0.value" >
```

This is for posting to a Drupal services api endpoint. This the format I need.

Comment: What do you mean your are passing the value?

Comment: formData.field_staff_interaction.und.0.value is a Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can't do `myArray.0`. Instead, you should do `myArray[0]`.
So, in your case, the correct form is:

```
$scope.formData.field_staff_interaction.und[0].value
```

It "works" with `ng-model` because this directive has its syntax, in which `myArray.0` is valid.

Comment: Can you give any clue on why it works in `ng-model`?

Comment: When I try to assign value by the above code, it gives me an error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'und' of undefined`

Comment: "_which ignores syntax errors_" is only valid if you are speaking in terms of Javascript syntax. It's an absolutely correct AngularJS syntax.

Comment: @esafwan This is because `$scope.formData.field_staff_interaction.und` at index `0` **is** `undefined`. You may have not initialised that array. If you show us more code maybe we can help you.